# How can I access label property for a control into a view in ZF2

Tags: forms, view, zend-framework2

Here is code from the view file, index.phtml:

```
<?php echo $this->formRow($form->get('daterange'));?>
```

Here is my code from the form file:

```
    $this->add(array(
        'type' => 'text',
        'name' => 'daterange',
        'options' => array(
            'label' => 'Start Time'
        ),
        'attributes' => array(
            'id' => 'daterange',
            'class' => 'form-control'
        ),
    ));
```

How can I access just label property for the daterange control? I need it because I want to improve my layout.

Comment: if $form->get('daterange') is a zend form element you should be able to retrieve it using $form->get('daterange')->getLabel()

Comment: Thanks! You know if in zend there is a function to get the control, like getLabel() get the label?

Comment: I don't understand your question

Comment: I found the solution  $this->formLabel($form->get('daterange'));  $this->formInput($form->get('daterange')); Maybe is more usefull to understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `$form->get('daterange')` si a Zend_Form_Element you can use getLabel() to retrieve the label from the element.

`$form->get('daterange')->getLabel();` // should do the trick.

But the best way to enhanced your layout would probably to add a custom decorator to your element and to trigger it via the Zend_Form_Element render() function.